# Как считать S.M.A.R.T параметры с USB-HDD диска?

Tags: c#, железо, hdd

Как считать S.M.A.R.T параметры с USB-HDD диска?

Желательно с примерами кода.

Читал, что программы по типу CrystalDiskInfo содержат информацию по каждому арибуту SMART для каждого производителя и что нет единой методики считывания этих параметров.

Comment: вообще .NET плохо дружит с "железом", специфика платформы. Даже для того что бы узнать банальный размер логического кластера, придется подключать неуправляемые DLL из WinAPI. Для вашей задачи скорее всего потребуется тоже самое. Подробнее к сожалению ответить не могу, но можно задать тот же вопрос спецам по C++ или гуглу, чтобы узнать название нужной DLL и параметры импорта, а дальше адаптировать под C#.

Comment: @rdorn: Если я правильно понимаю, C++ как язык тоже плохо дружит с «железом», нужно подключать внешние библиотеки (например, из WinAPI). Другое дело, что эти библиотеки часто имеют интерфейс на чистом C (так исторически сложилось уж), и поэтому их удобнее подключать к программам на C++. Но это не вопрос языка, а вопрос удобства interop'а.

Comment: @VladD не так уж и плохо, да, может не быть готовых функций, но прямой доступ к памяти творит чудеса, даже без асмовых вставок, но правда в ногу себе выстрелить также легко или даже легче =)

Answer (score 1):

Из всего путного, что я нашел - только эта статья (на английском) с примером кода: 
http://www.know24.net/blog/C+WMI+HDD+SMART+Information.aspx

Пример кода рабочий. Удачи.

Comment: Спасибо! Код рабочий, но, к сожалению, только для HDD. Как я понимаю, системе (Windows в моем случае) все равно, что на обратном конце USB-кабеля. `MSStorageDriver_FailurePredictData` содержит только данные для внутреннего HDD (IDE или SATA).

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте поискать в открытых исходниках.
Вот например что-то похожее:

https://github.com/arhimondr/SMARTMonitoring/blob/master/src/atasmart.c

Comment: Увы, этот код вызывает больше вопросов, чем дает ответы.

Comment: А разве этот код не для Linux API?